# How can I get the client's IP address if I am using HTTPS?

Tags: java, spring, http, https, ip

If I am using HTTP I can get the normal IP address but if I am using HTTPS it returns the proxy server's IP address. How can I get the IP address of the client and not the proxy server?

Comment: You mean "If I'm not using a proxy server I can get the client's IP address but if I am using a proxy server it returns the proxy server's IP address". HTTPS has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A proxy will generally add a `X-Forwarded-For` header [see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For) which will contain the IP address of the real client.

Note there's no difference between HTTP and HTTPS in terms of the IP addresses you can see on a request, they will both give you the IP address of the `User-Agent` that originated the request.